# How to exclude folders in sshfs mounting?

Tags: sshfs

Is it possible to mount a folder with `--no-recursive` option and `--folder-exclude`, `maxdepth`  options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [these docs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs), `sshfs` doesn't support `--no-recursive`, `--folder-exclude`,  `maxdepth`, or anything in the same vein (i.e. limit what's being mounted).

What you could try, if it's feasible for your use case, is make a selective clone of the remote dir on the remote machine, and mount that instead.

Comment: I can resolve the problem by using symlinks on the server side.